# Combining RSpec filters?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've been looking through the docs, but descriptions of how multiple filters work seem to be a bit lacking. Does anyone have a good explanation or source of a good explanation for the behaviour of multiple filters? Does the order they are listed matter? Here's an example of code that might have behaviour other than what one could expect...

```
Rspec.configure do |c|
  this_version = get_version_number.to_sym
  c.filter_run :focus=> true
  c.filter_run_excluding :limit_to=>true, this_version => false
  c.filter_run :new_stuff=>true
  c.run_all_when_everything_filtered
end

it "is focused, but not new", :focus
it "is is new", :new_stuff
it "is new and focused", :new_stuff, :focus
it "is focused and new, but limited to a different version", :focus, :limit_to, :correct_version
```

Experimenting with this, it also seems like multiple arguments on the "filter_run_excluding" line simple act is if you wrote the line multiple times. Is there a way to get it to actually combine the filter checks so that it excludes (or runs, I suppose) only examples that have both the tags listed?

Comment: If I /only/ want to run focused items, would it be better to use "filter_run_excluding :focus=>false"? I assume additional filter_runs will add items regardless of the "filter_run :focus=>true", correct?

Comment: I have this same question. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: This see like answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628880/can-i-use-multiple-exclusion-filters-in-rspec

Answer (score 3):

Run multiple filters from the command line with this:

```
rspec spec --tag my_tag --tag my_second_tag -- tag ~my_third_tag
```

The ~ will exclude any spec with those tags, so its often useful to do something like

```
rspec spec --tag ~long_runing
```

Comment: While true, does not answer the question.